# nodejs sub processes in nohup bash script lock up

Tags: kill, nohup, node.js

I run scripts with nohup that contain a list of a few hundred to a few thousand nodejs commands. These nodejs sub processes sync data from mysql and salesforce to couchdb.

```
$ nohup ./mf-sync.staging-mfdb.sh 2>&1 > mf-sync.staging-mfdb.log &
$ mf-sync.staging-mfdb.sh
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting..."
echo "pid $$"
node /opt/node/mix-sync/mf-sync.js --mfi=100017 --source=100982
node /opt/node/mix-sync/mf-sync.js --mfi=100026 --source=101619
node /opt/node/mix-sync/mf-sync.js --mfi=100027 --source=100982
node /opt/node/mix-sync/mf-sync.js --mfi=100036 --source=101619
node /opt/node/mix-sync/mf-sync.js --mfi=100063 --source=100982
node /opt/node/mix-sync/mf-sync.js --mfi=100075 --source=101160
etc....
```

In a terminal I observe the sub processes stalling:

```
[rgoya@host ~]$ ps -e | grep sync
   26 ?        00:00:00 async/mgr
   30 ?        00:03:34 sync_supers
 6333 ?        00:00:01 mf-sync
30097 ?        00:00:00 mf-sync.staging

[rgoya@host ~]$ ps -e | grep sync
   26 ?        00:00:00 async/mgr
   30 ?        00:03:34 sync_supers
 6333 ?        00:00:01 mf-sync
30097 ?        00:00:00 mf-sync.staging

[rgoya@host ~]$ kill 6333

[rgoya@host ~]$ ps -e | grep sync
   26 ?        00:00:00 async/mgr
   30 ?        00:03:34 sync_supers
 6423 ?        00:00:00 mf-sync
30097 ?        00:00:00 mf-sync.staging

[rgoya@host ~]$ ps -e | grep sync
   26 ?        00:00:00 async/mgr
   30 ?        00:03:34 sync_supers
 6449 ?        00:00:01 mf-sync
30097 ?        00:00:00 mf-sync.staging
```

**NOTE:** 30097 is the pid of the `nohup` process.

Examining the log before and after killing the subprocess, I see the next `nodejs` command is executed in sequence. I've tried running them with `--debug` flag for verbose output but I do not see anything unusual.

#### Additional notes

- Nodejs has a memory limit of 1GB.
- Couchdb defaults to 2048 max connections.
- The contents of `mf-sync.js`.

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env node
  process.title = 'mf-sync';

  var path = require('path')
  ,   fs = require('fs')
  ,   _ = require('underscore');

  // Parse command-line arguments
  var args = _.chain(process.argv).rest(2).map(function(arg) {
      arg = arg.replace('--', '').split('=');
      _.size(arg) === 1 && arg.push(true);
      return arg;
  }).object().value();

  if (!args.mfi) throw new Error('MFI ID not specified');
  if (!args.source) throw new Error('Source ID not specified');

  // Output when using `--debug` flag
  var debug = function() { if (_.has(args, 'debug')) console.info.apply(this, arguments); };

  // Simulation mode
  var simulate = _.has(args, 'simulate');

  require('util').log('Synchronization for ' + ['mfi', args.source, args.mfi].join('/') + ' started');
  simulate && console.warn('Simulation mode enabled. No changes will occurr.');
  debug(args);

  // Load MySQL configuration
  var my = require('mysql');
  var myConfig = require(path.join(__dirname, 'mysql.json'));
  var db = 'gold';
  if (args.source == '101027') db = 'mfdb';
  var mysql = my.createConnection(myConfig[db]);
  debug('MySQL', myConfig[db].database);

  // Load Salesforce configuration
  var sf = require('node-salesforce');
  var sfConfig = require(path.join(__dirname, 'salesforce.json'));
  var salesforce = new sf.Connection(sfConfig);
  debug('Salesforce', sfConfig.username);

  // Load CouchDB configuration
  var cradle = require('cradle');
  var couchConfig = require(path.join(__dirname, 'couchdb.json'));
  var couch = new(cradle.Connection)(couchConfig.mfdb.host, couchConfig.mfdb.port, couchConfig.mfdb.options).database(couchConfig.mfdb.name);
  debug('CouchDB', couchConfig.mfdb.name);

  // Add missing function to Underscore.js
  _.mixin({
      compactObject: function(obj) {
          _.each(obj, function(v, k) {
              if (_.isNull(v) || _.isFunction(v)) delete obj[k];
          });
          return obj;
      }
  });

  // Get MFI data from MySQL
  // -----------------------
  var getMySQLData = function(mfi, callback) {
      mysql.connect();

      // Get master MFI metadata
      debug('Getting master MFI metadata from `mfi`.');
      mysql.query("SELECT * FROM mfi WHERE source_id = ? AND mfi_id = ?", [mfi.source_id, mfi.mfi_id], function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) throw new Error(err);
          _.defaults(mfi, _.chain(rows).first().omit(['parse', '_typeCast']).value());
      });

      // Define MFDB data tables
      var tables = {
          'usd/false': ['balance_sheet_usd', 'calculation_usd', 'income_statement_usd', 'infrastructure', 'portfolio_report_usd', 'products_and_clients', 'social_performance'],
          'usd/true': ['balance_sheet_adjusted_usd', 'calculation_adjusted_usd', 'income_statement_adjusted_usd', 'infrastructure_adjusted', 'portfolio_report_adjusted_usd', 'products_and_clients_adjusted', 'social_performance'],
          'local/false': ['balance_sheet', 'calculation', 'income_statement', 'infrastructure', 'portfolio_report', 'products_and_clients', 'social_performance'],
          'local/true': ['balance_sheet_adjusted', 'calculation_adjusted', 'income_statement_adjusted', 'infrastructure_adjusted', 'portfolio_report_adjusted', 'products_and_clients_adjusted', 'social_performance']
      };
      // Remove table name variance
      var baseTable = _.memoize(function(table) {
          return table.replace('_usd', '').replace('_adjusted', '');
      });

      var docs = {};
      // Get all available MFDB data for the current `mfi_vid`
      debug('Getting all available MFDB data for the current `mfi_vid`.');
      _.each(_.keys(tables), function(key) {
          _.each(tables[key], function(table) {
              debug('Querying', key, 'data from', table);
              mysql.query("SELECT t.* FROM ?? t INNER JOIN mfi ON t.source_id = mfi.source_id AND t.mfi_id = mfi.mfi_id AND t.mfi_vid = mfi.mfi_vid WHERE t.source_id = ? AND t.mfi_id = ? ORDER BY t.fiscal_year ASC, t.period_type DESC, t.as_of_date ASC", [table, mfi.source_id, mfi.mfi_id], function(err, rows, fields) {
                  if (err) throw new Error(err);

                  // Create full document data
                  _.each(rows, function(row) {
                      // Create doc._id
                      var doc_id = ['mfi-period', mfi.source_id, mfi.mfi_id, key, row.fiscal_year, row.period_type, row.as_of_date.toISOString().substr(0, 10)].join('/');
                      debug('Processing', table, 'data for', doc_id);

                      // Initialize document
                      if (!docs[doc_id]) docs[doc_id] = {
                          _id: doc_id,
                          type: 'mfi-period',
                          currency: key.split('/')[0],
                          adjusted: key.split('/')[1] === 'true',
                          fiscal_year: row.fiscal_year,
                          period_type: row.period_type,
                          as_of_date: row.as_of_date
                      };
                      if (!docs[doc_id].currency_code && row.currency_code) docs[doc_id].currency_code = row.currency_code;

                      // Extend MFDB data into document
                      debug('Adding', table, 'data to', doc_id);
                      row = _.chain(row).omit(['mfi_id', 'mfi_vid', 'source_id', 'period_type', 'as_of_date', 'fiscal_year', 'currency_code', 'currency_unit']).compactObject().value();
                      if (!_.isEmpty(row)) docs[doc_id][baseTable(table)] = row;
                  });
              });
          });
      });

      // Get all scenario data to create dimension hierarchy
      var tree = {};
      mysql.query("SELECT * FROM scenarios", function(err, rows) {
          debug('Processing scenario data into hierarchical tree.');
          if (err) throw new Error(err);

          // Get all children scenarios for any given parent
          var getChildren = function(parent) {
              var children = _.chain(rows).where({parent: parent}).sortBy('weight').pluck('scenarios').object({}).tap(function(scenarios) {
                  // Remove used scenarios from master list to decrease stack size
                  _.each(_.keys(scenarios), function(scenario) {
                      rows = _.without(rows, _.findWhere(rows, {scenarios: scenario}));
                  });
              }).value();
              if (_.isEmpty(children)) return null;
              return children;
          }

          // Recursively get dimension hierarchy
          var getTree = function(hierarchy) {
              if (_.isEmpty(hierarchy)) return;
              _.each(_.keys(hierarchy), function(p) {
                  hierarchy[p] = getChildren(p);
                  if (!_.isEmpty(hierarchy[p])) getTree(hierarchy[p]);
              });
          }

          tree = getChildren('');
          getTree(tree);
      });

      // Find path to nested object property
      var findPath = _.memoize(function(needles, haystack) {
          function constructPath(haystack, needle, path) {
              if (!_.isObject(haystack)) return false;
              if (typeof haystack !== 'object') return false;
              for (var key in haystack) {
                  var value = haystack[key];
                  var currentPath = _.extend([], path);
                  currentPath.push(key);
                  if (key === needle) return currentPath;
                  var foundPath = constructPath(value, needle, currentPath);
                  if (foundPath) return foundPath;
              }
          }
          // Handle comma-separated nested hierarchies
          return _.chain(needles.split(',')).map(function(needle) {
              return constructPath(haystack, needle, []);
          }).flatten().compact().value();
      });
      // Assign value inside a nested object property
      var deepAssign = function(obj, path, val) {
          for (var i = 0 in path) {
              var key = path[i];
              if (i == path.length - 1) {
                  if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') obj[key].value = val;
                  else obj[key] = val;
              } else if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {
                  obj[key] = _.isUndefined(obj[key]) ? {} : {value: obj[key]};
              }
              obj = obj[key];
          }
      }
      // Sanitize dimension names
      var sanitizeDimensions = _.memoize(function(dimensions) {
          return _.map(dimensions, function(dimension) {
              dimension = dimension.replace(/mix_/g, '').replace(/Dimension/g, '').replace(/Member/g, '');
              if (/:/.test(dimension)) return dimension.split(':')[1];
              else return dimension;
          });
      });

      // Get dimension data for all available documents
      _.each(['usd', 'local'], function(currency) {
          var dimensions_table = currency === 'usd' ? 'dimensions_usd' : 'dimensions';
          debug('Querying', currency, 'data from', dimensions_table);
          mysql.query("SELECT d.fiscal_year, d.period_type, d.as_of_date, d.scenarios, d.line_item_value, t.db_table, t.db_field FROM ?? d INNER JOIN mfi ON d.source_id = mfi.source_id AND d.mfi_id = mfi.mfi_id AND d.mfi_vid = mfi.mfi_vid LEFT JOIN Taxonomy t ON d.element_id = t.Elementid WHERE d.line_item_value IS NOT NULL AND t.db_table IS NOT NULL AND t.db_field IS NOT NULL AND d.source_id = ? AND d.mfi_id = ?", [dimensions_table, mfi.source_id, mfi.mfi_id], function(err, rows, fields) {
              debug('Processing all data from', dimensions_table);
              if (err) throw new Error(err);
              _.each(rows, function(row) {
                  var dimension_path = findPath(row.scenarios, tree);
                  if (_.isEmpty(dimension_path)) return console.warn('MISSING SCENARIO', row.scenarios);
                  _.each(['true', 'false'], function(adjusted) {
                      var doc_id = ['mfi-period', mfi.source_id, mfi.mfi_id, currency, adjusted, row.fiscal_year, row.period_type, row.as_of_date.toISOString().substr(0, 10)].join('/');
                      var path = sanitizeDimensions([row.db_table, row.db_field].concat(dimension_path));
                      docs[doc_id] && deepAssign(docs[doc_id], path, parseFloat(row.line_item_value));
                  });
              });
          });
      });

      mysql.end(function(err) {
          debug('Disconnected from MySQL', db);
          if (err) throw new Error(err);
          callback(mfi, docs);
      });
  }

  // Get MFI metadata from Salesforce
  // --------------------------------
  var getSalesforceData = function(mfi, docs, callback) {
      var remaining = 4;
      var done = function(mfi, docs) {
          if (--remaining === 0) {
              callback(mfi, docs);

              // Logout from Salesforce
              salesforce.logout(function(err) {
                  debug('Logged out from Salesforce');
                  if (err) throw new Error(err);
              });
          }
      }

      // Login into Salesforce
      debug('Login into Salesforce');
      salesforce.login(sfConfig.username, sfConfig.password + sfConfig.security_token, function(err, userInfo) {
          if (err) throw new Error(err);

          // Get main MFI Metadata
          debug('Getting MFI metadata from Salesforce');
          salesforce.query("SELECT Id, Name, Record_ID__c, mix_Diamonds__c, Date_Established__c, mix_Region__c, Country__c, Operations_Comprised_by_MF__c, Regulated__c, Current_Legal_Status__c, Profit_Status__c FROM Account WHERE Record_ID__c = '" + mfi.mfi_id + "'", function(err, result) {
              if (err) throw new Error(err);
              if (result.totalSize === 0) throw new Error('MFI does not exist');
              var record = {};
              _.chain(result.records).first().omit(['attributes', 'Id']).each(function(v, k) {
                  // Make attributes lowercase
                  record[k.toLowerCase()] = v;
              });
              _.extend(mfi, record);
              mfi.mfi_name = mfi.name;
              done(mfi, docs);
          });

          // Determine whether MFI contains Social Performance Profile data
          debug('Determining whether MFI contains SP Profile data.');
          salesforce.query("SELECT Id, Record_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Record_ID__c = '" + mfi.mfi_id + "' AND Id IN (SELECT Organization__c FROM SP_Profile__c)", function(err, result) {
              if (err) throw new Error(err);
              mfi.sp_profile = !_.isEmpty(result.records);
              done(mfi, docs);
          });

          // Get list of MFI Network Affiliations
          debug('Getting list of MFI Network Affiliations');
          salesforce.query("SELECT Source_Organization__r.Name FROM Partnership__c WHERE Relationship__c = 'Network Affiliation' AND Status__c = 'Current' AND Target_Organization__r.Id = '" + mfi.organization_id + "'", function(err, result) {
              if (err) throw new Error(err);
              mfi.networks = _.chain(result.records).pluck('Source_Organization__r').pluck('Name').value();
              done(mfi, docs);
          });

          // Get annual diamonds
          debug('Getting annual diamonds.');
          salesforce.query("SELECT Period__c, Diamond_Score__c FROM Data_Campaign_Status__c WHERE Organization__c = '" + mfi.organization_id + "'", function(err, result) {
              if (err) throw new Error(err);
              // Group diamonds by year
              var diamonds = _.chain(result.records).map(function(period) {
                  return _.chain(period).pick(['Period__c', 'Diamond_Score__c']).values().value();
              }).object().value();
              // Add diamonds to corresponding periods
              _.chain(docs).filter(function(doc) { return doc.period_type === 'ANN'; }).each(function(doc) {
                  doc.annual_diamonds = diamonds[doc.fiscal_year];
              });
              done(mfi, docs);
          });
      });
  }

  // Calculate Peer Group data
  // -------------------------
  var calculatePeerGroupData = function(docs, callback) {
      // Safely get data point value
      var getVal = function(obj, group, prop) {
          if (_.has(obj, group) && _.has(obj[group], prop)) {
              return obj[group][prop].value || obj[group][prop];
          }
          return undefined;
      }

      _.each(docs, function(doc, id) {
          var peer_groups = {};

          // Age
          debug('Calculating peer group age for', doc._id);
          if (_.has(doc, 'date_established__c')) {
              var age = Math.abs(Date.parse(doc.as_of_date) - Date.parse(doc.date_established__c)) / (86400000 * 365.242199);
              if (age) {
                  if (age < 4) peer_groups['age'] = 'New';
                  else if (age <= 8) peer_groups['age'] = 'Young';
                  else if (age > 8) peer_groups['age'] = 'Mature';
              }
          }

          // Intermediation
          debug('Calculating peer group intermediation for', doc._id);
          var deposits = getVal(doc, 'balance_sheet', 'deposits');
          var total_assets = getVal(doc, 'balance_sheet', 'total_assets');
          if (!_.isUndefined(deposits) && !_.isUndefined(total_assets) && total_assets > 0) {
              var ratio = deposits / total_assets;
              if (ratio === 0) peer_groups['intermediation'] = 'Non FI';
              else if (ratio < 0.2) peer_groups['intermediation'] = 'Low FI';
              else if (ratio >= 0.2) peer_groups['intermediation'] = 'High FI';
          }
          else if (total_assets === 0) {
              peer_groups['intermediation'] = 'Non FI';
          }

          // Market
          debug('Calculating peer group market for', doc._id);
          var depth = getVal(doc, 'calculation', 'average_balance_borrower_per_capita') || getVal(doc, 'calculation', 'average_outstanding_balance_per_capita');
          var average_loan_size = getVal(doc, 'calculation', 'average_balance_borrower') || getVal(doc, 'calculation', 'average_outstanding_balance');
          if (!_.isUndefined(depth) || !_.isUndefined(average_loan_size)) {
              if (depth < .2 || average_loan_size < 150) peer_groups['market'] = 'Low End';
              else if ((depth >= .2) && (depth < 1.5)) peer_groups['market'] = 'Broad';
              else if ((depth >= 1.5)  && (depth < 2.5)) peer_groups['market'] = 'High End';
              else if ((depth >= 2.5)) peer_groups['market'] = 'Small Business';
          }

          // Outreach
          debug('Calculating peer group outreach for', doc._id);
          var total_borrowers = getVal(doc, 'products_and_clients', 'total_borrowers');
          if (total_borrowers < 10000) peer_groups['outreach'] = 'Small';
          else if (total_borrowers < 30000) peer_groups['outreach'] = 'Medium';
          else if (total_borrowers >= 30000) peer_groups['outreach'] = 'Large';

          // Scale
          debug('Calculating peer group scale for', doc._id);
          if (_.has(doc, 'mix_region__c')) {
              var gross_loan_portfolio = getVal(doc, 'balance_sheet', 'gross_loan_portfolio');
              if (gross_loan_portfolio < 2000000 || (gross_loan_portfolio < 4000000 && doc.mix_region__c == 'Latin America and The Caribbean')) peer_groups['scale'] = 'Small';
              else if (gross_loan_portfolio < 8000000 || (gross_loan_portfolio < 15000000 && doc.mix_region__c == 'Latin America and The Caribbean')) peer_groups['scale'] = 'Medium';
              else if (gross_loan_portfolio > 8000000) peer_groups['scale'] = 'Large';
          }

          // Sustainability
          debug('Calculating peer group sustainability for', doc._id);
          var operational_self_sufficiency = getVal(doc, 'calculation', 'operational_self_sufficiency');
          if (!_.isUndefined(operational_self_sufficiency)) {
              if (doc.adjusted) peer_groups['sustainability'] = operational_self_sufficiency < 1 ? 'Non-FSS' : 'FSS';
              else peer_groups['sustainability'] = operational_self_sufficiency < 1 ? 'Non-OSS' : 'OSS';
          }

          if (!_.isEmpty(peer_groups)) docs[id].peer_groups = peer_groups;
      });

      callback(docs);
  }

  // Send data to CouchDB
  // --------------------
  var updateCouchDB = function(docs, callback) {
      // Update master MFI record
      debug('Updating master MFI record');
      var mfi = docs.shift();
      couch.get(mfi._id, function(err, doc) {
          if (err) {
              if (err.error === 'not_found') {
                  require('util').log('Inserting ' + mfi._id);
                  !simulate && couch.save(mfi._id, mfi, function(err, res) {
                      debug('Inserted', res);
                      if (err) throw new Error(err);
                  });
              } else throw new Error(err);
          } else if (doc._rev) {
              require('util').log('Updating ' + mfi._id);
              !simulate && couch.save(mfi._id, doc._rev, mfi, function(err, res) {
                  debug('Updated', res);
                  if (err) throw new Error(err);
              });
          }
      });

      // Get list of existing IDs in CouchDB
      debug('Getting list of existing IDs in CouchDB');
      couch.all({startkey: ['mfi-period', args.source, args.mfi].join('/'), endkey: ['mfi-period', args.source, args.mfi, '~'].join('/')}, function(err, ids) {
          if (err) throw new Error(err);

          // Remove outdated documents from CouchDB
          _.chain(ids).pluck('id').difference(_.pluck(docs, '_id')).map(function(id) {
              return _.findWhere(ids, {id: id});
          }).each(function(doc) {
              require('util').log('Removing ' + doc.id);
              couch.remove(doc.id, doc.value.rev, function(err, res) {
                  debug('Removed', res);
                  if (err) throw new Error(err);
              });
          });

          // Insert/update all documents for this MFI
          _.each(docs, function(doc) {
              var update = _.findWhere(ids, {id: doc._id});
              if (update) {
                  require('util').log('Updating ' + doc._id);
                  !simulate && couch.save(doc._id, update.value.rev, doc, function(err, res) {
                      debug('Updated', res);
                      if (err) throw new Error(err);
                  });
              } else {
                  require('util').log('Inserting ' + doc._id);
                  !simulate && couch.save(doc._id, doc, function(err, res) {
                      debug('Inserted', res);
                      if (err) throw new Error(err);
                  });
              }
          });

          callback();
      });
  }

  // Initialize MFI document
  var mfi = {
      _id: 'mfi/' + args.source + '/' + args.mfi,
      type: 'mfi',
      source_id: args.source,
      mfi_id: args.mfi,
      updated: new Date()
  };

  getMySQLData(mfi, function(mfi, docs) {
      getSalesforceData(mfi, docs, function(mfi, docs) {
          // Merge MFI metadata into each period
          _.each(docs, function(doc, id) {
              docs[id] = _.extend(_.clone(mfi), doc);
          });
          calculatePeerGroupData(docs, function(docs) {
              // Convert to array for bulk updating
              docs = _.union([mfi], _.values(docs));
              updateCouchDB(docs, function() {
                  require('util').log('Synchronization for ' + ['mfi', args.source, args.mfi].join('/') + ' finished');
              });
          });
      });
  });
  ```

#### Questions

I would like to know:

1. Why these sub processes appear to freeze? (I cannot find any evidence that the ones that freeze are any different than the ones that execute and stop).
2. How I might be able to script stopping a sub process that freezes for several minutes, so that I do not have to kill it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Have to guess that you are running out of some kind of resource (although you probably are already guessing that).  Maybe max files open, or mysql, or salesforce.  Don't know.

But one way you might be able to resolve it is instead of that bash script with a ton of those mf-sync things, put mf-sync in a module and use a controlling Node script that uses a queue to run this mf-sync thing sort of in controlled batches with the queue.  Try something like https://github.com/learnboost/kue

Seems kind of crazy the way you are doing it.  But if it is just running out of files, maybe you can get away with just increasing the limit.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Or if you really want to do it in the shell, maybe you can use the `batch` command to handle the queue.  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/batch.html

Or maybe something like this would be better http://pebblesinthesand.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/a-srcipt-for-running-processes-in-parallel-in-bash/

Comment: Actually, the script is a workaround for a node module that should run the processes with eachSeries - but that seems to stop too. So that is why we are running them line by line (with a script that generates the necessary lines). Also if I log the shorter version ~260 commands with tee instead of > that one seems to complete.

Comment: But it still running them sequentially so if one stops it halts the whole thing.  This is the type of thing you use a queue for.  Kue allows concurrent processing and possibly timeouts. Linux has a 'timeout' command you can also try that. Add a process.uncaught exception handler.  Post the debug log and also move to stack overflow because this is a programming problem.